# Blender Crashing on Startup

Tags: installation

Ever since yesterday, blender has been crashing during it's startup sequence. It shows its normal little window of code, but then doesn't load. It worked just fine earlier in the morning yesterday, but hasn't worked since yesterday afternoon. I haven't done anything different with my PC; I've reinstalled blender multiple times, and I've been using 2.79b and there's no way I'm settling for an older version, and I've installed the latest drivers, but still no luck. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Possibly you have a problem with an addon. Try removing (or moving - so you can put it back if needed) the local config. On Windows this will be somewhere like c:/users/USER/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/2.79

Comment: Can you add Image of the Error you see?

Answer (score 1):

I found that for some reason, blender, even though absolutely nothing uses it since I have a dedicated Graphics Card, wants me to have the integrated intel graphics enabled on my CPU. Not sure why, but it works just fine so long as I have that enabled through the BIOS.